# Interações com o "0" da calculadora nas funções

Tags: javascript, front-end

Como todos sabem aquele "0" que toda calculadora tem seja ele quando você abre a calculadora, reseta os valores ou deleta todos os valores ele aparece na tela da calc, gostaria de uma ajuda de como poderia implementar ele em minha calculadora em JS.

```js
getAndShowKeys = (button) => {
  const inputKeys = document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML += button.value;
};

clearInput = (button) => {
  document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML = "0";
};

deletButtons = (button) => {
  const inputResult = document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML = inputResult.substring(0, inputResult.length - 1);
};

operationsResult = (button) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML = eval(result);
};
```

```html
<!-- SCREEN RESULT -->
<section class="screen">
  <p class="internal-screen-result " id="screenResult">0</p>
</section>

<!-- CALCULATOR BODY -->
<section class="buttons-container">

  <div class="buttons-area">

    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="9">9</button>
    <button class="del-button" onclick="deletButtons(this)">DEL</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="6">6</button>
    <button onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="+">+</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="3">3</button>
    <button onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="-">-</button>
    <button onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value=",">.</button>
    <button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="0">0</button>
    <button onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="/">/</button>
    <button onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="*">x</button>

    <!-- DIF BOTTONS -->
    <div class="reset-igual-position">
      <button class="reset-button" onclick="clearInput(this)">RESET</button>
      <button class="igual-button" onclick="operationsResult(this)" value="=">=</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução seria substituir o elemento HTML `<p>` usado como "visor":

```
 <p class="internal-screen-result " id="screenResult">0</p>
```

por um elemento HTML `<<input type="text">` ajustando o atributo [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) para zero(`0`):

```
<input type="text" class="internal-screen-result " id="screenResult" readonly placeholder="0">
```

Junto dessa mudança também pode remover os [Manipuladores de Eventos Inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#manipuladores_de_eventos_in-line_-_n%C3%A3o_use_esses) e os substituir pelo mecanismo de gerenciamento de eventos mais atual [addEventListener() e removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#addeventlistener_e_removeeventlistener).
Essa modificação permite separ o código HTML do JS, assim facilitando a leitura e analise com seu código, fora a facilidade de deixar atribuir eventos manualmente a cada tag na página e então poder atribuir e remover de forma automatizada os seus eventos a [arvore DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) do documento.

```js
//Obtém as referencias para alguns elementos da calculadora. 
const display = document.querySelector('#screenResult');
const rstBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-button');
const dotBtn = document.querySelector('.dot-button');
const delBtn = document.querySelector('.del-button');
const eqBtn = document.querySelector('.igual-button');

//Cria um array com os operadores.
const oprs = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];

//Para elemento elm cujo a classe seja num adiciona o seu evento click. 
for (let elm of document.querySelectorAll(".num")) {
  elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    display.value += e.target.value;
  })
}

//Para elemento elm cujo a classe seja opr adiciona o seu evento click.
for (let elm of document.querySelectorAll(".opr")) {
  elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (display.value == "") return;
    if (oprs.includes(display.value[display.value.length - 1])) return;
    display.value += e.target.value;
  })
}

//Para elemento elm cujo a classe seja dot adiciona o seu evento click.
dotBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (display.value == "") {
    display.value = "0.";
    return;
  }
  if (oprs.includes(display.value[display.value.length - 1])) {
    display.value += "0.";
    return;
  }
  if (display.value == ".") return;
  display.value += e.target.value;
});

//Adiciona o evento do botão DEL
delBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  display.value = display.value.slice(0, -1);
});

//Adiciona o evento do botão RESET
rstBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  display.value = "";
});

//Adiciona o evento do botão =
eqBtn.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  display.value = eval(display.value);
});
```

```css
#screenResult {
  text-align: right;
  border: 0;
}

#screenResult::placeholder {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- SCREEN RESULT -->
  <section class="screen">
    <input type="text" class="internal-screen-result " id="screenResult" readonly placeholder="0">
  </section>

  <!-- CALCULATOR BODY -->
  <section class="buttons-container">
    <div class="buttons-area">
      <button class="num" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="num" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="num" value="9">9</button>
      <button class="del-button">DEL</button><br>
      <button class="num" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="num" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="num" value="6">6</button>
      <button class="opr" value="+">+</button><br>
      <button class="num" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="num" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="num" value="3">3</button>
      <button class="opr" value="-">-</button><br>
      <button class="dot-button" value=".">.</button>
      <button class="num" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="opr" value="/">/</button>
      <button class="opr" value="*">x</button>

      <!-- DIF BOTTONS -->
      <div class="reset-igual-position">
        <button class="reset-button">RESET</button>
        <button class="igual-button">=</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Não tinha visto que estava fechada.